# Is it possible to empty the inbox (mobile phone) in an automated way?

Tags: java-me

I am looking for a solution to delete the contents of my inbox automatically when a threshold is reached . Can this be done in J2ME programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there are no libraries in J2ME that make this possible.

My assumption would be because there is no standard way of connecting to the inbox from Java as it is implemented differently between mobile operating systems. Some handset manufacturers might have a proprietary API to access the inbox, but there is no common way to achieve this from Java.

Comment: SMS inbox handling is potentially part of midp3

Answer (score 0):

RIMS extensions for Blackberries Java allow you to access emails in the messages folders but not SMS